# How can I target the src attribute of the img element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can target an `id` with jQuery using `$("#yourId")`, but how can I target the src attribute of the `img` element since it's not an `id`. I want to link the api's images link directly.

I have a `<div> <img src"">` `</div>`

var `ico = data.weather[0].icon`

I want ico in `src""` using jquery.

Comment: Did you use a JS Framework? If you use a JS Framework, which one?

Comment: May i please you to share a Code snipped. It easier to help, when we can see more information.

Comment: this is pure JS

Comment: If you use `$("#yourId")` to access the `id`, you are using jQuery, don't you?

Comment: You are right Peter

Comment: Your updated question doesn't match what you asked in the first place.

Comment: @Z.Mrwan I updated my answer, please check if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target elements with attributes.

```
$('img[src="imageurl"]')
```

If you only want to track images with part of an URL use this:

```
$('img[src*="partOfTheImageUrl"]')
```

This checks if the `src` attribute contains your string.

**EDIT**

Since you changed your question, I will change my answer too.

To set the `src` of an image use this:

```
$('img').attr('src', ico);
```

You may want to use another selector instead of `img`. As example an ID like you already described in your question.

Comment: my imageUrl is a variable, i cant put a variable in your method. Any idea?

Comment: @Z.Mrwan Yes you can `$('img[src="' + $imageUrl + '"]')`

Comment: @z.Mrwsn Of course you can. Just concatenate it in.

Comment: @Z.Mrwan true. I still recommend another selector. With this one you will select all images on the whole page.

Comment: You are right, do you have an exemple of another selector? Like giving an Id to <img>? edit: It also work if I target an id within the <img> element.

Comment: @Z.Mrwan yes you can basically do any combination that you like and that makes sense. In your example probably an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var y = $("img[src$='img.png'][name='img']");
console.log(y.attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img.png" name="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery selectors, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Here is the sample HTML

```
<img src='imgUrl'/>
<img src='imgUrl2'/>
<img src='imgUrl3'/>
<img src='notIncluedimgUrl'/>
<ul id ="Result"></ul>
```

And here is the working JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('img[src^="imgUrl"]').each(function(i, e){
    $("#Result").append("<li>" + $(e).prop("src") + "</li>");
  });
});
```

And here is the result:

- file:///C:/Users/rcv/Desktop/imgUrl
- file:///C:/Users/rcv/Desktop/imgUrl2
- file:///C:/Users/rcv/Desktop/imgUrl3

I have uploaded to JSFiddle, so you can run it.

https://jsfiddle.net/j5eyzqr3/1/